# Location return null on the phone

Tags: android, location

I want check my current latitude and longitude. This code is working at the emulator but when i check at phone i have null.(android 10)
The application on the phone has location permission.

```
    fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if(location!=null){
                MyLong=location.getLongitude();
                MyLat=location.getLatitude();
                test.setText(MyLat+" " +MyLong);
            }
            else{
                test.setText("null");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you add necessary permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [official android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current), there are some situations that the last known location could be null and those are

- Location is turned off in the device settings. The result could be
  null even if the last location was previously retrieved because
  disabling location also clears the cache.
- The device never recorded its location, which could be the case of a
  new device or a device that has been restored to factory settings.
- Google Play services on the device has restarted, and there is no
  active Fused Location Provider client that has requested location
  after the services restarted

In those situations you should [request location updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates). You could check the [example of Google's Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/while-in-use-location/?hl=ko#0)